# Creating a channel that only one role can join

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a channel for a message author that only members from the `partyInvitees` collection (`Collection<Snowflake, GuildMember>`) can join.

```
const permission = Discord.Permissions.FLAGS;

message.guild.createRole({
  name: message.author.username + "'s Party",
})
.then(role => {
  message.guild.createChannel(message.author.username + "'s Party", 'voice')
  .then(channel => {
    channel.setParent('401856302290042884');
    channel.overwritePermissions(role, { [permission.CONNECT]: true, [permission.SPEAK]: true });
    partyInvitees.forEach(user => user.addRole(role));
    message.reply("your party's all set-up");
  });
});
```

I have a CategoryChannel parties, id `401856302290042884`, and I'm trying to create a voice channel inside of that.

I'd like only people with the `message.author.username + "'s Party"` role to be able to join this voice channel.

The permissions on the parent channel `401856302290042884` are all turned off for the @everyone role

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, we're going to assume that the channel is *not* synced with the category, and that the category does not have "Read Text Channels & See Voice Channels" set to false. On creation of the channel, you're not setting @everyone's see voice channel permission to false, while you are setting the role's permissions. You have step two down, but you're missing step one. To fix this, we have to set @everyone's permission of "See Voice Channel" to false, while setting the role's See Voice Chanel permission to true. We can do using the [overwritePermissions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions) method that you're using to set the role's permissions:

```
const everyone = message.guild.roles.find("@" + "everyone"); // We seperate it that way if it's run in eval, it won't tag.
channel.overwritePermissions(everyone, {"VIEW_CHANNEL": false});
```

If you insert the above before your overwritePermissions for the role, it should give the effect you're looking for. Happy coding!

Comment: on the category _everything_ is set to false

Comment: If the channel is still not synced with the category (as I don't believe they are on bot creation), that would mean that either way the channel would not have the desired effect.